# SSIS two staging tables

Tags: ssis

I would like to bring in an XML source and do data conversion and update it in a table. Data from this table will be used to update another table. How to accomplish this in SSIS?

I understand the first two steps. But lost after that.

1. XML Source (under dataflow task)
2. Data Conversion
3. OLE DB Destination? (If I use OLE DB Destination, then I cannot use that as a source again to update another table). What component should I be using to accomplish this?

TIA

Answer (score 2):

Within a dataflow you can split the records to go to multiple tables using either a conditional split (if you want some records to go one way and some to go another way) or a mulicast task if you want all records to go to both destinations. We use a multicast to create two staging tables, one where the raw data from the file will stay and one where the data will be cleaned and transformed before going into our prod tables. This enables us to easily research if some problem data that came in was due to our transformation process (a bug) or bad data being sent (a problem at the client end, but which might require more steps to handle if they can't fix).

You can also have multiple data flows that all have the same source. Or you can insert to one staging table and then have a second data flow or exec SQL task to move that data to where you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the OLE DB Destination to inject your XML source data into your staging table. Then, in your control flow use an Execute SQL task after your data flow task to execute a stored procedure or T-SQL script to move your data from the staging table into the production table(s) and truncate the staging table if required.

I've found that SSIS is great for ETL work, but moving data around inside a DB or aggregation work is best carried out using T-SQL in stored procs. Easier to write, control and you know you're not going to have any RBAR shenanigans you can happen upon in a DFT.

YMMV